# Check if this method is good to unique ids

Tags: php

I'm trying to create ids to diversified contents using md5 to encode but, I'm not sure about this method.

```
<?php    
$prefix = 'stackoverflow';
$length = 11;
$id = md5( $prefix . uniqid(microtime()) );

$part1 = substr($id, 0,(floor($length / 2))); //First 5 chars

$id = strrev($id); //Reverse md5

$part2 = substr($id, 0,(ceil($length / 2))); //First 6 chars of the reversed md5

$final_id = $part2 . $part1; //Reverse final id
?>
```

Comment: Sorry what are you trying, to create a unique id?

Comment: What are the requirements for the ids? Does it need to be a certain length? Does it need to have specific characters? Do they need to be globally unique, or just within a certain system? Do they need to be guaranteed unique at creation time, or can you check against an index?

Comment: There's also the [uniqid function](http://us2.php.net/uniqid).

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to reinvent a wheel.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

> **string uniqid ([ string $prefix = "" [, bool $more_entropy = false ]] )**
>
> Gets a prefixed unique identifier based on the current time in microseconds.

Also you might want to use real globally unique identifiers (windows specific extension)

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.com-create-guid.php

Answer (score 0):

The thing with random, unique ids is *entropy*. I.e., does it contain enough *random* data to be mathematically guaranteed to be unique in practice?

```
$id = md5( $prefix . uniqid(microtime()) );
```

Here, `$prefix` is static and adds no entropy. `microtime` is not random at all, and although the chance that it produces the same value twice is very low, it exists. `uniqid` adds a bit more entropy to that value, which is probably good enough in practice. After this you hash the value and reduce its length, which means you're removing entropy again.

Overall, you add very little entropy from the beginning and reduce some afterwards, which overall does not leave me with a good feeling. It's *probably* going to be good enough for a small site in practice, but I would not bet on it.

All you really need is a random number generator, which is built into your OS in almost all cases:

```
$id = bin2hex(file_get_contents('/dev/urandom', false, null, -1, 32));
```

Functions which wrap this include [`openssl_random_pseudo_bytes`](http://php.net/openssl_random_pseudo_bytes) and [`mcrypt_create_iv`](http://php.net/mcrypt_create_iv). Trying to reinvent a random number generator by using some seemingly confusing string concatenation is futile, that is not true randomness (neither is `/dev/urandom` *truly random* in most cases, but it approximates it a lot better than you ever will). Depending on your situation you may also want to go with [UUIDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUIDs) to begin with.